# Как перевести int в char?

Tags: типы-данных, java

Кто знает, как перевести `int` в `char[]`? Очень надо. (Можно даже с посредниками, ну, вроде byte'ов.)

Comment: Не совсем ясно, чего Вы хотите добиться?  
Диапазон целого ограничен 0-255 или целое может быть любым, например, 100500?

Comment: одно значение int в массив символов char[] ??

Comment: Значение восьмизначное. Да, одно значение в один массив.

Comment: ну так создай цикл, в котором определишь длину int переменной, затем другим циклом по одной циферке (каждый разряд - еденицы, десятки сотни) клади в массив char[]. Где у тебя проблема возникла, лучше опиши. Тут не телепаты.

Comment: Я новичок, никогда не пользовал char. Если можно, напиши код. Первый цикл мне не нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужен char[]? Тип String = char[], соответственно:

```
int myAwesomeInt=12345678;
String myAwesomeString=String.valueOf(myAwesomeInt);
//теперь можно вот так получить доступ к char
char myAwesomeChar=myAwesomeString.charAt(4);
System.out.print(myAwesomeChar);//выведет "5"
```

Если нужно совсем char[], то делаем так:

```
char[] myAwesomeCharArray=new char[myAwesomeString.lenght()];
for(int i=0; i<myAwesomeString.lenght(); i++)
{
myAwesomeCharArray[i]=myAwesomeString.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int number = 123456789;
char[] array = Integer.toString(number).toCharArray();
```